# PHP MD5 of array object does not match MD5 in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, md5

I am trying to do validate data sent over the net using the MD5 hash.

This is the PHP server code that prepares, encodes and returns the data:

```
$sdata = array('action' => $action,
               'client' => $client,                  
               'mobile' => $mobile,
               'orders' => []);

$sdata_md5 = md5(json_encode($sdata));

$response = array('sdata' => $sdata,
                  'sdata_md5' => $sdata_md5);

echo json_encode($response);
```

This is the SWIFT iOS code that receives the server data and attempts to calculate the MD5 hash of the received data:

```
do {

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
                                data, response, error in
        if error == nil {

            if let _data = data {

                if let dataArr = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: _data) as? [String : Any] {                    

                    let sdata = dataArr["sdata"] as? [String : Any]                                                

                    let sdata_md5 = dataArr["sdata_md5"] as? [String : Any]

                    let calc_md5 = sdata.description.md5

                    // calc_md5 != sdata_md5 ?    

                }

            }

        }
```

And this is the SWIFT extension for the MD5:

```
extension String {

    var md5: String {

        let data = Data(self.utf8)
        let hash = data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> [UInt8] in

            var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
            CC_MD5(bytes.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &hash)

            return hash

        }

        return hash.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()

    }

}
```

If the server sends a single simple string the MD5 matches, but not with the array object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are trying to cast `sdata_md5` as a dictionary not array.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni How should I cast it as array?

Comment: you can use `if let` or `guard let` and cast it `as? [[String: Any]]` and you need to make sure that you are receiving correct data from server which can be cast as Array.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni So: `let sdata = dataArr["sdata"] as? [[String : Any]]` ?

Comment: yes it should work

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I'll give that a try. Thank you.

Comment: Hashes are also probably order-dependant. Since dictionaries don't have a defined ordering, this entire effort is futile, unless you establish some canonical ordering (that's consistent not only between separate instances of your Swift app, but also between Swift and PHP). Sorting your dictionary into an array of key-value pairs (ordered by their keys, alphabetically) could do the trick